# Is there an way to access AWS RDS database by StringRequest URL in android app?

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services, server, amazon-rds

I'm very new to server system and have been struggling over making login system work on android app that I'm developing.

I connected RDS database with AWS EC2 server but have no idea how to access to RDS database with app.

Here is class I'm using for server:

public class ValidateRequest extends StringRequest {

```
final static private String URL = "https://localhost/UserValidate.php";
private Map<String, String> parameters;

//    send parameter values to database by posting method
public ValidateRequest(String userID, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, URL, listener, null);
    parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("userID",userID);
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
    return parameters;
}
```

}

When program is executed, it doesn't display any error messages. I'm thinking my URL variable is set wrong but have no idea how to fix it. Can anyone suggest what to do here?

my php files are located under /var/www/html remote site. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a month late but I'm guessing this will be useful for anyone else that has the same problem. This answer assumes you have made the necessary security group settings for the rds instance (like making it accessible publicly, although I would only recommend doing that for development purposes).

This answer uses volley as well albeit using a singleton class for the request queue.

Solution -

**1. PHP constants file. (Declare your database constants)**

```
define ('DB_HOST',  'aws rds access point goes here');

define ('DB_USER', 'rds user name goes here ' );

define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'rds password goes here ');
```

**2. PHP Connection file. (Initiate connection)**

```
require_once "constants.php";

$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
if($con)
{

 $sql = "SQL Query";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 //Whatever you echo here will be treated as the response at the android end
 //Can be JSON,string etc.

}
```

**3. Java file. (Initiate String request in android)**

This is an example of how it would look like if you were trying to login users into your application.

```
 private void login(final String emailText, final String passText) {
        final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Error is " + error.toString());
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map <String,String> params  = new HashMap<String,String>();

                params.put(Constants.KEY_EMAIL,emailText);
                params.put(Constants.KEY_PASSWORD,passText);

                return params;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

**4. Java singleton class. (Recommended to use if you're making a lot of requests)**

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private static Context ctx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```